# Ubuntu store on bq Aquaris M10 tablet doesn't show anything

Tags: ubuntu-store

I have reinstalled but again the Ubuntu store doesn't show anything. And now I don't have terminal nor file manager. The system is updated though last update is from 25/02/17, Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-15).
Is there something I could do?
Thanks for help.

raf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Phone is discontinued. You should install [latest firmware from ubports](https://devices.ubports.com).